# Geodesics under Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, connections

I read somewhere that minimum energy paths are geodesics under the Levi-Civita connection, on a Riemannian energy landscape.

The [Levi-Civita connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection) is the "unique connection on the tangent bundle of a manifold that preserves the Riemannian metric and is torsion-free".

What exactly is the intuition of geodesics under the Levi-Civita connection? Why would torsion-free connections give geodesics with least energy?

Comment: What exactly are you calling a *torsion-free geodesic*? In general, the word "torsion-free" refers to the connexion, not the geodesic.

Comment: @Didier right, edited.

Comment: Some clarifications: The energy of a curve (path) is defined using the Riemannian metric (and not the Levi-Civita connection). When you compute the variational formula for energy, the Levi-Civita connection appears naturally. The fact that the Levi-Civita connection preserves the metric is used in this. The critical points of energy are constant speed geodesics. But constant speed geodesics are not necessarily energy minimizing. They are locally energy minimizing (any sufficiently short piece of the curve is energy minimizing).,

Comment: @Deane interesting, so does this mean the Levi-Civita connection can be derived by minimizing the energy of a curve with the constraint that the speed is constant? Or that this is a equivalent definition of the L-C connection?

Comment: I don't think so. The variational equation uses only the Levi-Civita connection for the covariant derivative of the velocity vector of a curve with respect to itself. This, I believe, is not enough to define the connection for two arbitrary vector fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\nabla$ is any connection and $f$ a function, its Hessian with respect to $\nabla$ is $\mathrm{Hess}^{\nabla}f = \nabla \mathrm{d}f$, and one can see, after a messy calculation, that:
$$
\mathrm{Hess}^{\nabla}f(X,Y) - \mathrm{Hess}^{\nabla}f(Y,X) = \pm\mathrm{d}f\left([X,Y] - (\nabla_XY - \nabla_YX) \right)
$$
(where the $\pm$ sign is here because I don't remember the exact sign, but the computations are not that hard, just messy.) Hence, Hessians are symmetric if and only if the connection is torsion-free. This is the main motivation to consider torsion-free connections: in the euclidean space, Hessians are symmetric!

Moreover, the fundamental theorem of Riemannian geometry tells us that on a Riemannian manifold, there is a unique connexion that is torsion-free and lets the metric invariant, that is:
$$
\forall X,Y,Z, \left(\nabla_Zg\right)(X,Y) = Z\cdot g\left(X,Y \right) - g\left(\nabla_ZX,Y\right) - g\left(X,\nabla_ZY\right) = 0.
$$
(compare with the euclidean case, where $\langle X,Y\rangle ' = \langle X',Y\rangle + \langle X, Y' \rangle$.)
This theorem thus says that given any Riemannian metric $g$, there is a connection that is better than others: Hessians are symmetric and the metric is invariant under the  action. We call it the Levi-Civita connexion.

If a connection is chosen, a geodesic is a parametrized curve satisfying the equation of geodesics : $\nabla_{\gamma'}\gamma' = 0$. Thus a curve $\gamma$ is a geodesic *with respect to the connection*, and can be a geodesic for some connection $\nabla^1$ but not for another connecion $\nabla^2$. Therefore, your question does not really have sense: we do not say that a connexion gives the least energy of a geodesic. I think you got confused, believing that being a geodesic is an intrinsic notion, but it really depends on the connection you consider.

Now, suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold endowed with its Levi-Civita connexion. Then if $\gamma : [a,b] \to M$ is a curve, we define its energy to be:
$$
E(\gamma) = \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b \|\gamma'\|^2
$$
and one can show that, in the space of all curves $\{\gamma : [a,b] \to M\}$ with same end points, a curve $\gamma$ is a point where the energy functional is extremal if and only if $\nabla_{\gamma'}\gamma'=0$, that is if and only if $\gamma$ is a solution of the equation of geodesics. Hence, a minimizer of the energy functional is a geodesic.

Comment: Quibble: $\nabla_{\gamma'}\gamma' = 0$ implies the parameterized curve is not just a geodesic but a constant speed geodesic.

Comment: Thanks! So your definition of a geodesic as an energy-minimizer gives different geodesics (and different minimum energies) based on which $\nabla$ we use. I'm still unsure about why the Levi-Civita connection in particular provides a smaller minimum energy compared to other choices of connection.

Comment: The Levi-Civita does not provide a minimum energy compared to other connection: this, I think is another question that is unrelated. Also, I did not define geodesics as energy minimizing curves. I defined the as solution to the equation of geodesics.

Comment: @Didier well, geodesics by definition minimize energy under the given connection. My interpretation of the statement "minimum energy paths are geodesics under the Levi-Civita connection" has the emphasis on "under the L-C connetion" rather than "are geodesics". So I was wondering why (or whether) the energy-minimizer over geodesics is the one under the L-C connection.

Comment: +1 by the way for the explanation about geodesics being energy-minimizing paths.

Comment: My definition of geodesic is not as an energy minimizer: this is a consequence of my definition, which is based on the geodesic equation. Also, I think the sentence "minimum energy paths are geodesic under the L-C connection" has to be understood that way: fixing the L-C connection, that is related to the Riemannian structure, one can show that geodesics are minimizers of the energy functional. There is nothing to do with other connections.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion here. The geometric definition of a geodesic is with respect to a Riemannian metric, which allows you to define the length of a geodesic. Given two points, a length-minimizing geodesic is defined to be the curve of shortest length connecting the two points. If you compute the variational formula for the length functional, you get an ODE that is a necessary but not sufficient condition for a curve to be length-minimizing. So we call a curve that satisfies this equation a (not necessarily length-minimizing) geodesic

Comment: As for the energy functional, you can show that a curve joining two specified points minimizes energy if and only if it is a length-minimizing geodesic *and* its parameterization has constant speed. That's a particularly nice parameterization, so we usually use the energy instead of length functional. Again, the variational formula for energy give an ODE. We call any solution to this ODE a constant speed geodesic. The ODE is a necessary but not sufficient condition for the curve to be energy-minimizing.

Comment: The Levi-Civita connection arises here only because the ODE can be written nicely using it. However, you could do everything without it and use only the Riemannian metric and its partial derivatives. The calculations are messier, and it's harder to interpret the formulas geometrically, if you don't use the connection.

Comment: @Deane, thank you. This seems to make sense and I tried to do my own derivation. However where does the Levi-civita connection 'arise naturally'? (It seems it should come up in the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange eqns from the energy-minimization problem, but I'm not comfortable enough with the details.)

Comment: For where the Levi-Civita connection comes from, you can look at my answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/387539/613 and the answers here (including one of mine own): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376486/what-is-the-levi-civita-connection-trying-to-describe